# Is it insecure to execute code via an HTTP URL?

Tags: r, security, bioinformatics, bioconductor, man-in-the-middle

I'm suspicious of the installation mechanism of [Bioconductor](http://www.bioconductor.org/install/). It looks like it is just executing (via `source()`) the R script from an HTTP URL. Isn't this an insecure approach vulnerable to a man-in-the-middle attack? I would think that they should be using HTTPS. If not, can someone explain why the current approach is acceptable?

Comment: While my particular question is about Bioconductor, I'd be interested to hear general responses about when/whether HTTP is acceptable for running remote scripts, not necessarily just in R.

Comment: See also: https://support.bioconductor.org/p/68458/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you are correct.

Loading executable code over a cleartext connection is vulnerable to a MITM.

Unless loaded over HTTPS where SSL/TLS can be used to encrypt and authenticate the connection, or unless the code has been [signed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_signing) and verified at the client then a MITM attacker could alter the input stream and cause arbitrary code to be executed on your system.

Answer (score 0):

Allowing code to execute via a HTTP `GET` request essentially means you're allowing user-input to be directly processed by the application thus directly influencing the behavior of the application. Whilst this is often what the developer would like (say to query specific information from a database) it may be exploited in ways as you have already mentioned (E.g MITM). This is often (however I'm not directly referring to Bioconductor in any way) a bad idea as it opens the system to possible XSS/(B)SQLi attacks amongst others.

However the URL - http://bioconductor.org/biocLite.R is essentially just a file placed on the Web Server and from what is seems `source()` is being used to directly download it. There does not seem to be any user-input anywhere in this example so no, I wouldn't mark is as unsafe; however your analogy is indeed correct.

Note: This is simply referring to GET requests - E.g: `http://example.com/artists/artist.php?id=1`. Such insecurities could be exploited in many HTTP requests such as Host Header attacks, however the general concept is the same. No user-input should *ever* be directly processed by the application in *any* way.

Comment: `source()` doesn't just download the file, it also executes the contents of the file. That's the part that troubles me.

Comment: @WillTownes - Then yes, that may be an issue that would worry me as well. I suggesting delving deeper on how `source()` works as there may be security limitations present within the function itself that we may have missed. Granted, I literally nothing nothing about how `R` works.